# Call SHGetImageList in Go

Tags: windows, winapi, go

I'm trying to call SHGetImageList in Go in order to extract icons from .EXE files. The problem is that I don't know how to create/pass an "IImageList2 interface" in Go, which is something SHGetImageList requires.

I've tried miscellaneous things for a few hours, but it all results in the same E_NOINTERFACE error. Basically they're all "shots in the dark" ([]byte array to see if I could receive any "data" at all, an actual interface{} in Go containing the same functions as the IImagelist2 interface defined by MSDN, etc). If it is of any relevance, I do have a working version of this in C# using something along the lines of http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shgetimagelist, but I simply have no real clue on how to "translate" that to Go. Any help would be much appreciated.

Example Go code below, with some info and links to MSDN in the comments.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    shell32 = syscall.MustLoadDLL("shell32.dll")

    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx
    procSHGetFileInfo = shell32.MustFindProc("SHGetFileInfoW")

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185(v=vs.85).aspx
    procSHGetImageList = shell32.MustFindProc("SHGetImageList")
)

func main() {
    someExeFile := `c:\windows\explorer.exe`

    iconIndex := GetIconIndex(someExeFile)

    // The problem:
    HRESULT, _, _ := procSHGetImageList.Call(
        uintptr(SHIL_JUMBO),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&IID_IImageList2)),

        // I don't know how pass/create an "IImageList interface" in Go,
        // or if it's even possible without relying on CGO.
        // IImageList interface:
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761419(v=vs.85).aspx

        // Currently there's just a pointer to an empty []byte so that the code will compile.
        // HRESULT naturally contains the error code E_NOINTERFACE (2147500034),
        // which makes sense seeing as I'm not passing a valid interface.
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&[]byte{})),
    )

    fmt.Println(iconIndex, HRESULT)
}


const SHIL_JUMBO = 0x4

const shGetFileInfoLen = 3
const shGetFileInfoFlags = 16400 //(SysIconIndex|LargeIcon|UseFileAttributes)
// use SHGetFileInfo to get the icon index (only value we care about)
func GetIconIndex(fileName string) int {
    buf := make([]uint16, shGetFileInfoLen)
    ret, _, _ := procSHGetFileInfo.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(fileName))),
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])),
        shGetFileInfoLen,
        shGetFileInfoFlags,
    )

    if ret != 0 && buf[2] > 0 {
        return int(buf[2])
    }

    return 0
}

// From: "192B9D83-50FC-457B-90A0-2B82A8B5DAE1"
var IID_IImageList2 = &GUID{0x192b9d83, 0x50fc, 0x457b, [8]byte{0x90, 0xa0, 0x2b, 0x82, 0xa8, 0xb5, 0xda, 0xe1}}

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx
type GUID struct {
    Data1 uint32
    Data2 uint16
    Data3 uint16
    Data4 [8]byte
}
```

**UPDATE**

The problem now is that it's exiting with an error(0xC0000005) when calling the Syscall to get the actual icon pointer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    shell32 = syscall.MustLoadDLL("shell32.dll")

    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx
    procSHGetFileInfo = shell32.MustFindProc("SHGetFileInfoW")

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185(v=vs.85).aspx
    procSHGetImageList = shell32.MustFindProc("SHGetImageList")

    ole32 = syscall.MustLoadDLL("ole32.dll")
    procCoInitialize = ole32.MustFindProc("CoInitialize")
)

func main() {
    someExeFile := `c:\windows\explorer.exe`

    procCoInitialize.Call()

    iconIndex := GetIconIndex(someExeFile)

    var imglist *IImageList
    hr, _, _ := procSHGetImageList.Call(
        uintptr(SHIL_JUMBO),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&IID_IImageList)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&imglist)),
    )

    // These look OK
    fmt.Println(iconIndex, hr, imglist.Vtbl.GetIcon)

    var hIcon uintptr
    // GetIcon: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761463(v=vs.85).aspx
    hr, _, _ = syscall.Syscall(imglist.Vtbl.GetIcon,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(imglist)),
        uintptr(iconIndex),
        getIconFlags,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&hIcon)),
    )

    // Errors: "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

    fmt.Println("hIcon:", hIcon) // Never reaches this
}

// ILD_TRANSPARENT | ILD_IMAGE
const getIconFlags = 0x00000001 | 0x00000020

const SHIL_JUMBO = 0x4

const shGetFileInfoLen = 3
const shGetFileInfoFlags = 16400 //(SysIconIndex|LargeIcon|UseFileAttributes)
// use SHGetFileInfo to get the icon index (only value we care about)
func GetIconIndex(fileName string) int {
    buf := make([]uint16, shGetFileInfoLen)
    ret, _, _ := procSHGetFileInfo.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(fileName))),
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])),
        shGetFileInfoLen,
        shGetFileInfoFlags,
    )

    if ret != 0 && buf[2] > 0 {
        return int(buf[2])
    }

    return 0
}


// From: "46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950"
var IID_IImageList = GUID{0x46eb5926, 0x582e, 0x4017, [8]byte{0x9f, 0xdf, 0xe8, 0x99, 0x8d, 0xaa, 0x09, 0x50}}

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx
type GUID struct {
    Data1 uint32
    Data2 uint16
    Data3 uint16
    Data4 [8]byte
}

type IImageList struct {
    Vtbl *IImageListVtbl
}

type IImageListVtbl struct {
    Add                uintptr
    ReplaceIcon        uintptr
    SetOverlayImage    uintptr
    Replace            uintptr
    AddMasked          uintptr
    Draw               uintptr
    Remove             uintptr
    GetIcon            uintptr
    GetImageInfo       uintptr
    Copy               uintptr
    Merge              uintptr
    Clone              uintptr
    GetImageRect       uintptr
    GetIconSize        uintptr
    SetIconSize        uintptr
    GetImageCount      uintptr
    SetImageCount      uintptr
    SetBkColor         uintptr
    GetBkColor         uintptr
    BeginDrag          uintptr
    EndDrag            uintptr
    DragEnter          uintptr
    DragLeave          uintptr
    DragMove           uintptr
    SetDragCursorImage uintptr
    DragShowNolock     uintptr
    GetDragImage       uintptr
    GetItemFlags       uintptr
    GetOverlayImage    uintptr
}
```

Comment: *"HRESULT naturally contains the error code E_NOINTERFACE (2147500034), which makes sense seeing as I'm not passing a valid interface."* - I don't see, why that makes sense. The *ppv* argument to `SHGetImageList` is an **out** parameter. It is returned by the API call. You are required to pass the address of a pointer that receives the interface pointer on return.

Comment: The E_NOINTERFACE return value is from the syscall itself, not related to the pointer or the arguments/data I'm passing IN the syscall. If the syscall is successful it should return `S_OK` which is 0. For me it "makes sense" that I'd get the "no interface" error code because presumably that's what Windows returns when it doesn't see the third(the ppv) argument in that syscall as a "valid" interface (?)

Comment: Windows doesn't know what `ppv` is. It uses the `iid` to determine which interface to use. I wonder if `SHGetImageList()` supports IImageList2... Which IImageList2 method did you need to call?

Comment: Only GetIcon. `SHGetImageList()` works with `IImageList2` in C#, I'll give IImageList a try right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I see the actual problem now.

```
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&IID_IImageList2)),
...
var IID_IImageList2 = &GUID{0x192b9d83, 0x50fc, 0x457b, [8]byte{0x90, 0xa0, 0x2b, 0x82, 0xa8, 0xb5, 0xda, 0xe1}}
```

Your `IID_IImageList2` is already a pointer. In your call, you're taking a pointer to that pointer, which means the address is used as the GUID. You should either do

```
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&IID_IImageList2)),
...
var IID_IImageList2 = GUID{0x192b9d83, 0x50fc, 0x457b, [8]byte{0x90, 0xa0, 0x2b, 0x82, 0xa8, 0xb5, 0xda, 0xe1}}
```

or

```
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(IID_IImageList2)),
...
var IID_IImageList2 = &GUID{0x192b9d83, 0x50fc, 0x457b, [8]byte{0x90, 0xa0, 0x2b, 0x82, 0xa8, 0xb5, 0xda, 0xe1}}
```

That way, the GUID itself is used as the GUID, not its location in memory.

Comment: .. Yeah, silly mistake there. But that fixes it! Thanks a bunch for your help! Also tried the `StringFromGUID2` that you briefly suggested in a comment earlier and it matched the original strings.

Answer (score 2):

Interfacing COM with Go is going to be **painful**.

A COM interface like IImageList2 is a list of function pointers, and you can't use those C function pointers from Go directly; you have to use `syscall.Syscall()` and its siblings (depending on the number of arguments the individual function takes) to call them.

At its core, a COM interface instance is a structure whose first and only field is a pointer to this list of methods. So it'd be something along the lines of

```
type IImageList2Vtbl struct {
    QueryInterface uintptr
    AddRef         uintptr
    Release        uintptr
|

type IImageList2 struct {
    Vtbl *IImageList2Vtbl
}
```

When you pass a pointer to a variable of type `IImageList2` to the Windows API function you call to create that object, be it `SHGetImageList()`, `CoCreateInstance()`, `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain()`, or what have you, the system will fill in the `Vtbl` entry with a pointer in **read-only** system memory that contains the list of functions.

So the first thing you have to do is make sure the methods are in the right order, so the Go structure `IImageList2Vtbl` and the list that Windows will give you match. Unfortunately, MSDN isn't good at this; you'll have to spelunk through the header files. Here's what I get:

```
type IImageList2Vtbl struct {
    QueryInterface       uintptr
    AddRef               uintptr
    Release              uintptr
    Add                  uintptr
    ReplaceIcon          uintptr
    SetOverlayImage      uintptr
    Replace              uintptr
    AddMasked            uintptr
    Draw                 uintptr
    Remove               uintptr
    GetIcon              uintptr
    GetImageInfo         uintptr
    Copy                 uintptr
    Merge                uintptr
    Clone                uintptr
    GetImageRect         uintptr
    GetIconSize          uintptr
    SetIconSize          uintptr
    GetImageCount        uintptr
    SetImageCount        uintptr
    SetBkColor           uintptr
    GetBkColor           uintptr
    BeginDrag            uintptr
    EndDrag              uintptr
    DragEnter            uintptr
    DragLeave            uintptr
    DragMove             uintptr
    SetDragCursorImage   uintptr
    DragShowNolock       uintptr
    GetDragImage         uintptr
    GetItemFlags         uintptr
    GetOverlayImage      uintptr
    Resize               uintptr
    GetOriginalSize      uintptr
    SetOriginalSize      uintptr
    SetCallback          uintptr
    GetCallback          uintptr
    ForceImagePresent    uintptr
    DiscardImages        uintptr
    PreloadImages        uintptr
    GetStatistics        uintptr
    Initialize           uintptr
    Replace2             uintptr
    ReplaceFromImageList uintptr
}
```

> *I'm sure I got this wrong; please report any errors. :)*

This comes from `commoncontrols.h`. Go with the C-style, not C++-style, interface definitions (if there are more than one), as that will have all the methods, including those of interfaces that IImageList2 derives from (IUnknown, which all interfaces derive from, and IImageList).

Er wait, I lied: Windows doesn't expect you to give it the memory for the IImageList2. That's because COM interfaces are just like Go interfaces: they're a set of methods that any implementation can implement. So in reality you have to let Windows give you a pointer to an `IImageList2`, not an `IImageList2Vtbl`.

So what do we do? We store each instance as a pointer to the interface, and then pass a pointer to *that* to the creation functions.

So from that, we have

```
var imglist *IImageList2
hr, _, _ := procSHGetImageList.Call(
    uintptr(SHIL_JUMBO),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&IID_IImageList2)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&imglist)),
)
```

Notice that we pass a pointer to the IImageList2. I'll call this the *instance*, and the `Vtbl` member the *vtable*.

Now when you want to *call* a method, you have to add an extra first parameter: the *instance* itself. You can look on MSDN for the return types and other parameters:

```
// HRESULT EndDrag(void);
hr, _, _ = syscall.Syscall(instance.Vtbl.EndDrag,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(imglist)))
// HRESULT SetOverlayImage(int, int);
hr, _, _ = syscall.Syscall(instance.Vtbl.SetOverlayImage,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(imglist)),
    4,
    2)
```

Notice that we pass `imglist` this time, not `&imglist`.

Now because C and C++ don't support multiple returns like Go does, functions typically return a HRESULT (the COM equivalent of Go's `error`) and have you pass in pointers to the rest of the return values at the end of the argument list. For other COM interfaces, we follow the rules above. For other type, we [refer to the Windows Data Types page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what each named type represents, and remember that C `int` is always Go `int32` on Windows, even on 64-bit systems.

```
// HRESULT AddMasked(HBITMAP, COLORREF, (OUT) int *);
// we'll use uintptr for HBITMAP and int32 for COLORREF
var index int32
hr, _, _ = syscall.Syscall(instance.Vtbl.AddMasked,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(instance)),
    hbitmap,
    mask,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&index)))
```

Finally, COM requires us to call the `Release()` method when we're done with an object. This takes no extra parameters and its return value is irrelevant. You can stuff this in a `defer` if you want.

```
syscall.Syscall(instance.Vtbl.Release,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(instance)))
```

---

> *Note: I don't know if `SHGetImageList()` requires COM to be initialized. If it doesn't, ignore this part until you need some other COM interface.*

Oh but that's not enough, because you also have to initialize COM. And COM can operate in a number of threading models. Only two are important: single-threaded apartment, which is used for anything related to GUI, and multithreaded apartment, which is used for special purposes.

The `CoInitialize()`, `CoInitializeEx()`, and `CoUninitialize()` functions all handle COM initialization and uninitialization. You already know how to call them; they're just normal DLL functions.

But beware! If you need a single-threaded apartment, **you have to use `runtime.LockOSThread()` to ensure Go doesn't move the current goroutine to another OS thread from under you**. If you don't do this, things will break in bizarre ways.

---

This is all a load of work, and you have to do it for every interface you're going to use. You might as well use a package that someone already made that does the heavy lifting for you. There are several packages, such as `go-ole`, that do the basic stuff. I don't see one that provides `IImageList2`, but you might be able to piggyback off an existing one. [There seems to be only one reference for `IImageList`.](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=IImageList+language%3AGo&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

**Good luck!**

Comment: First off, thanks for the reply! But unfortunately, unless I'm missing something, this doesn't solve the actual problem at hand. What you're saying makes perfect sense. But even when passing the `var imglist *IImageList2` to the procSHGetImageList call, I'm still left with a E_NOINTERFACE return value and a nil pointer. Any thoughts?

(P.S. I've tried both with and without CoInitialize())

Comment: Another question, been trying for a while now, and calling it like you described with `syscall.Syscall(...)` but I'm only getting access violation errors (0xc0000005). Any ideas why? I'll check back tomorrow, I desperately need some sleep.

Comment: Sure, I updated the original post with the current code. I've also tried some variations with Syscall6 and so on without really getting anywhere, the current Syscall has the same format as you had in your original reply. (Although you had a separate `instance` and `imglist` but I'm _guessing_ that's more of a "typo"?)

Comment: `hIcon` is an output parameter; you want to pass its address (`&hIcon`).

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, was just a typo. Deleted the multiple syscalls I had while testing and wrote the one you see to just generate the error. But this doesn't fix the issue, regardless of how I'm passing hIcon the error is the same. Could it be something with the arguments? I'm unsure as to why the second argument passed in your example is `uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(imglist))` when from what I can tell it should be an int telling Go how many arguments are actually used in the Syscall. (Note that I've tried some variations of this as well with no success)

Comment: Ah, if I got the `syscall.Syscall()` wrong you should just follow what godoc says to use. I can fix my answer if that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah I think you did, but the thing is, if I use what I think is the right approach: `hr, _, _ = syscall.Syscall(imglist.Vtbl.GetIcon, 3, uintptr(iconIndex), getIconFlags, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&hIcon)))` Then I'm left with a hIcon == 0 and a hresult with the error E_NOTIMPL (0x80004001). Which is where I'm stuck at the moment, any thoughts on this?

Comment: You forgot the `imglist` parameter in that call. It should be `hr, _, _ = syscall.Syscall(imglist.Vtbl.GetIcon, 4, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(imglist)), uintptr(iconIndex), getIconFlags, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&hIcon)))`

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too, you need to use Syscall6, currently that would look like this: `hr, _, _ = syscall.Syscall6(imglist.Vtbl.GetIcon, 4, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(imglist)), uintptr(iconIndex), getIconFlags, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&hIcon)), 0, 0)` but it still results in the same E_NOTIMPL hresult, and I don't know why.

Comment: Never mind, it "is" working. The current problem seems to be that it doesn't retrieve a handle for SHIL_JUMBO. While a C++ version of it I made gets the SHIL_JUMBO handle just fine, so it's probably an entirely different issue. Anyways, again, thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. If the code is correct, then I wouldn't know as I'm not familiar with those APIs, sorry. Good luck!